# Regexp Not working with file_get_contents for span tag

Tags: php, regex

Hi below is my `Regexp` which works well when I directly assign html content to it. but not working with file_get_contents()

```
<?php 
$url = "http://www.apdepot.com/Products/SearchResults.aspx?type=keyword&keyword=6-918873";

$urlcontent = file_get_contents($url);

/*  It works when I assign html content to it but now working with file_get_contents(). 

 $urlcontent = '<td width="80%" valign="top" align="left">
                          <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0">*WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734</span> <input type="hidden" value="*WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_hdnP21Desc_0" name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Repeater1$ctl01$hdnP21Desc">
                          </td>'; */


preg_match_all('/<span.*id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0\".*>(.*?)<\/span>/Us', $urlcontent, $name);
        print_r($name);
```

Expected Output -

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0">*WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734</span>
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => *WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734
        )

)
```

### Update

### Same thing not working for anchor tag

```
$url = "http://www.apdepot.com/Products/SearchResults.aspx?type=keyword&keyword=6-918873";

    $urlcontent = file_get_contents($url);

    $name = '<td valign="top" align="left" class="SearchResultItemHeader">
                    <a class="thickbox" title="Dishwasher Tube/Spray Arm Kit" href="ItemDetailsPopup.aspx?itemcode=WHI%20675808&amp;keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=500&amp;width=640"><b>Dishwasher Tube/Spray Arm Kit</b></a>                          
                      </td>';

    preg_match_all('/<a.*class=\"thickbox\".*title=\"(.*?)\".*href=\"ItemDetailsPopup.aspx\?itemcode.*\">.*<b>(.*)<\/b><\/a>/s', $name, $nameoutput);
    print_r($nameoutput);
```

Expected Output -

text within  tag

```
Dishwasher Tube/Spray Arm Kit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
preg_match_all('/<span id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0\".*>(.*)<\/span>/Us', $urlcontent, $name);
```

output:

```
Array

    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0">*WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734</span>
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => *WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734
            )

    )
```

For data scrapping xpath is best option. Have a look on below example:

```
$url = "http://www.apdepot.com/Products/SearchResults.aspx?type=keyword&keyword=6-918873";

$urlcontent = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($urlcontent);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//span[@id='ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0']")->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $elements;

//output: *WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734
```

for more detail have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php and http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

example for `anchor` tag and `b` tag:

```
$urlcontent = '<td valign="top" align="left" class="SearchResultItemHeader">
                    <a class="thickbox" title="Dishwasher Tube/Spray Arm Kit" href="ItemDetailsPopup.aspx?itemcode=WHI%20675808&amp;keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=500&amp;width=640"><b>Dishwasher Tube/Spray Arm Kit</b></a>
                      </td>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($urlcontent);

$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);

$elements = $xpath->query("//td[@class='SearchResultItemHeader']/a/b")->item(0)->nodeValue;

echo $elements;

////output: Dishwasher Tube/Spray Arm Kit
```

Comment: Hi Chetan, Same thing is not working for a href .. I its working with when directly passing html contents

Comment: Please check updated question

Comment: on website the order of class and href is different in order, i think for such case you can use xpath for scrapping data

Comment: how it works .. can you please provide an example.

Comment: see updated answer.. you can get other tags on basis of xpath

Comment: can you give me the exact link of the webpage so i can send xpath for anchor tag

Comment: This is the link http://www.apdepot.com/Products/SearchResults.aspx?type=keyword&keyword=6-918873 .. As there are many attribute in anchor tag. Inspect webpage and find this `<td valign="top" align="left" class="SearchResultItemHeader">
                        <a class="thickbox" title="*WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE" href="ItemDetailsPopup.aspx?itemcode=WHI%206-918873&amp;keepThis=true&amp;TB_iframe=true&amp;height=500&amp;width=640"><b>*WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE</b></a>                          
                          </td>`  I want =>>  WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE

Comment: Hi Chetan, please check above comment

Comment: I have added the example for the same

Answer (score 0):

Change Regexp like this -

```
preg_match_all('%<span.*id=\"ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0\"(.*)\/span>%', $urlcontent, $desc);
```

Then you can apply strip_tags() like below

```
$description = strip_tags($desc[1][0]);
```

Output -

```
Array

    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [0] => <span id="ContentPlaceHolder1_Repeater1_lblLongDesc_0">*WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734</span>
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [0] => *WAS W10224675 M BASKT-WARE WAS W10171734
            )

    )
```